# C++ debug console shows error message about python

Tags: python, c++, macos

i try to run a simple programme on CodeLite in OSX system:
[image]

and i see result like this in the console screen:

[image]

the message about python is annoying, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Not an _OSX_ user, but you should remove the _virtualenvwrapper.sh_ scrip from your profile file to avoid being executed at login time. Or, of course set the correct _PTYHONPATH_ so that _Python_ finds the _virtualenvwrapper_ module.

Comment: The message's there to help you, not annoy you. If you do as it says, it'll go away.